# A div that dynamically keeps the body's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my div to fit the body's height and always touch the bottom of my body when I scroll, so I made it 100% height.

But I've quickly understood that isn't the right solution. When another div goes away from the window, when I scroll, I see my div scrolling with a margin right down to it between the bottom and it.
So I've just made a small snippet in jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
var pageHeight = $(document).height();
$('#menu').css('height', 'px');
$('#menu').css('height', pageHeight + 'px');
});
```

But it doesn't work well.
So I don't know what to do.

Comment: `$('#menu').css('height', 'px');` remove this

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle.net as an example as it's not quite clear what you want from the question.

Comment: instead of `$(document).height();` use `$(window).height();`

Comment: Thanks Peter for having corrected me, and thanks for all the replies. @RobSchmuecker take a look on my test ftp please: http://verypgm.net16.net/portfolio/home.php (more simple).

Comment: @Amin Jafari it does the same... :/

Comment: I still don't really understand.  For some reason you page "grows" when I scroll?!

Comment: Indeed, that's the problem of my script haha!(i corrected some mistakes since you've tried it but it does the same...) It's so frustrating... there isn't a margin to the bottom anymore but it stills not working correctly... I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean that (CSS):

```
div {
    height: 100vh; // 100% of view height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, di don't know why but, i set my div's height like that:

```
min-height:900;
height: 100%;
max-height:200%;
```

And it works... i really don't know why. Anyway, I don't need help anymore.
Thanks to everybody who helped me!

Comment: Yes it is (I'm not a css exppert but i'm seeing it, it works..); I want my div to be, as less, 900px height. I agree, it really sounds dirty, but it works perfectly and my document is never gonna be more than 200% so it's not a problem... And the div grows when needed...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, you can change the menu height with its body height.

```
$(window).resize(function(){

  $('#menu').height($(document).height());

});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was one of the solutions i've tried, but it does something wired when i resize, the div grows again and again and again...